# XPath - Selection TD next to the selected XPath table which contains SPAN

Tags: html, xpath

I have a table and I'm trying to get data from via xpath. A simple example of the table looks like this:

```
horse   id1 id2       id3      id4
abc      1   1         1        1
123      2   2         2        2
cba      3   3   <span>3</span> 3
321      4   4         4        4
```

What I want to do is look at column `id3` and find the row that contains the span code (in this case it's row 3). Once I have this I would like to get the value in column 1 of that row (the one that span is on) which would be cba.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Share html code.

Comment: added simple code

Comment: Is this any better - sorry its my first time posting

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match `tr` that contains `span`, then you might use below `XPath`:

```
//table[1]//tr[.//span]/td[6]/a[1]
```

Also note that you can use less complex and more verbose expressions by using attributes of target/parent/child/sibling element.

Suppose you need to match link

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a class="link new-link" href="/some/source">Click me!</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

you can use

```
//a[text()="Click me!"]
```

and

```
//a[@href="/some/source"]
```

and

```
//a[@class="link new-link" and text()="Click me!"]
```

... and a lot of other combinations

Comment: The span has to be specific to td[15] so td 15 must contain span (its only 1 row that will contain it)

Comment: I don't get your point... Have you tried my answer? It doesn't work?

Comment: No it didn't work how I wanted it to. I have added a further explanation

Answer (score -1):

Try this below code.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td/span"));

for(int i=0;i<elements.size();i++)     
{
    System.out.println(elements.get(i).getText());   //Will give you only those data which `<td>` contains `<span>` tag.
}
```

**Updated Answer**

If you want only fourth column `<td>` data contains `<span>` tag refer below code.

suppose your html look this.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>horse</th>
        <th>number1</th>
        <th>number2</th>
        <th>number3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>horse1</td>
        <td>3424</td>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>-----</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>horsename2</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td><span>data2</span></td>
        <td>-----</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>horsename2</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>-----</td>
        <td><span>data3</span></td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

refer this code.

```
int b = 1;      
int[] array_list = new int[] {1,2,3};    //int b presents `<tr>` tag.

for(int i =0; i<array_list.length;i++)
{
    WebElement  span_source = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//th[4]/..//following::tr["+b+"]/td[4]"));

    try
    {
        WebElement  span = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//th[4]/..//following::tr["+b+"]/td[4]/span"));  
        System.out.println(span.getText());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("TD tag not contains data with span tag.");
    }

    b++;
}
```

Comment: Hi - I don't actually know the horse name as with is what I'm trying to find

Comment: Hey - I don't know the horses name - this is what I'm trying to look up by finding the span in col4

Comment: all i want is 
IF column d1 contains <span></span>  get a1
IF column d2 contains <span></span>  get a2

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please check and let me know your problem is getting resolved or not?

Comment: Ok so getting the span is not my issue its getting column 1 where psan is in column 4

Comment: You can get data of td which contains span of all columns. have you tried this code?

Comment: You have provided only 3 columns in above html code, column name as `horse, number1,number2` Where is column 4 ? check your html first.

Comment: No this code will work in java lang. i don't know anything about python lang.